# Need help on writing sql query with dynamic columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to write a query which does below. I tried but couldn't write. Please help me.

I have table which returns below result set.

```
select * 
from table1;  --(rowid and ColumnName are columns of the table)
```

Output:

```
rowid       ColumnName
------------------------------
   1        Segment1    
   2        Segment2
```

I have another table which has below structure : (Segment1 and Segment2 are columns here)

```
select *  
from table2;
```

Output:

```
appId     Segment1     Segment2      Segment3
---------------------------------------------
  a1      fld1         fld2          per
  a2      cmp1         hcd4          klp
```

I need to write a query, which reads the "ColumnName" values from first table and retrieves column values in the second table.

That means, from  the table1, I will know what are the available columns I the table2 and from table2, I will know what is the data stored against those columns.

Please let me know if I am not clear. 
This query is in Oracle SQL

Comment: What is the query to the first table.. i.e  on what basis do you select if the output from table 1 is segment1 or segment2 ?

Comment: I need to read all ColumnName values in the table1 and retrieve  their values from the table2.

Comment: The values from the column "ColumnName" from table1 should get mapped with the column names in the table 2 and should return the values

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: In Oracle ROWID is the address of a record. You should not use it for a column name. (I am surprised this is even possible.) Then columns should never contain column or table names unless you are writing a DBMS and hence you are dealing with tables, columns, and such. (For instance the system table all_tab_cols contains column names, but this is a table written by Oracle themselves as part of their DBMS.) In short: change your database design.

Comment: You need a PLSQL block for your requirement. You will be needing to write a dynamic sql to do so

Comment: @ThorstenKettner..I cannot comment on database design as I am very new to this project. I am working on assigned task. I will keep in mind,your inputs. Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you need a PLSQL block with dynamic sql. See below an example:

Tables:

```
create table table1 (row_id number,
                     ColumnName varchar2(100)) 

create table table2 (appId     number,   
                     Segment1  varchar2(100),
                     Segment2  varchar2(100),    
                     Segment3  varchar2(100));

 Insert all   
    into TABLE1 (ROW_ID, COLUMNNAME)  Values    (1, 'Segment1')
    into TABLE1 (ROW_ID, COLUMNNAME)  Values    (2, 'Segment2')
    into TABLE2 (APPID, SEGMENT1, SEGMENT2, SEGMENT3)  Values  (1, 'RRR', 'KKK', 'MMM')
    into TABLE2 (APPID, SEGMENT1, SEGMENT2, SEGMENT3)  Values  (2, 'ZZZ', 'PPP', 'QQQ')
    into TABLE2 (APPID, SEGMENT1, SEGMENT2, SEGMENT3)  Values  (3, 'LLL', 'NNN', 'DDD')
 select * from dual;
```

Code:

```
DECLARE
   var     VARCHAR2 (1000);
   v_sql   VARCHAR2 (2000);
   TYPE x_var IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000);
   z_var   x_var;
   num number:=0;
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN (  SELECT DISTINCT columnname
                   FROM table1
                  ORDER BY 1)
   LOOP          
      num := num +1;      
      if num = 1 then
       var:= rec.columnname;       
       else
         var := var || ' || '' , ''||' || rec.columnname;
      end if; 

   END LOOP;

   var := RTRIM (LTRIM (var, ','), ',');   

   v_sql := 'select '|| var ||' from table2';    

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql BULK COLLECT INTO z_var;

   FOR i IN 1 .. z_var.COUNT
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (z_var(i));
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Output:

```
SQL> /
RRR , KKK
ZZZ , PPP
LLL , NNN
```

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic columns in a SQL statement are almost always a bad idea.  There's usually a way to avoid these kind of problems and build a simpler solution.

But if this is one of those rare times when you *really* need to run dynamic SQL in SQL then you'll need to install and run something like my open source project [Method4](https://github.com/method5/method4).

For example:

```
create table table1 as
select 1 id, 'Segment1' columnName from dual union all
select 2 id, 'Segment2' columnName from dual;

create table table2 as
select 'a1' appId, 'fld1' Segment1, 'fld2' Segment2, 'per' Segment3 from dual union all
select 'a2' appId, 'cmp1' Segment1, 'hcd4' Segment2, 'klp' Segment3 from dual;

select * from table(method4.dynamic_query(
    q'[
        select
              'select appID, '
            ||listagg(columnName, ',') within group (order by id)
            ||' from table2'
            sql_statement
        from table1
    ]'
));

APPID   SEGMENT1   SEGMENT2
-----   --------   --------
a1      fld1       fld2
a2      cmp1       hcd4
```

There are a lot of downsides to running this way.  The code is complicated, slow, and has some odd behavior.  For an explanation of how this works, see [this article](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=422)
 by Adrian Billington.

Answer (score 0):

Will the below PL SQL block help your requirement.

```
BEGIN
FOR iter IN (
                SELECT column_name
                FROM all_tab_columns
                WHERE upper(table_name) = 'table1'
                AND UPPER(column_name) LIKE 'SEGMENT%'
            )       
        LOOP
            SELECT iter.column_name INTO temp_table FROM table1
            dbms_output.put_line(temp_table.column_name);
        END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: A little description within your answer covering how the SQL you've provided works would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have tables like the following:

```
SQL> select * from someTable;

   COLUMN1    COLUMN2    COLUMN3
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3
         2          4          6
         3          6          9

SQL> select * from tableOfColumns;

COLUMNN
-------
column1
column3
```

You may need something like the following:

```
SQL> declare
  2      type    tListOfResults is table of varchar2(1000);
  3      vSQL    varchar2(1000);
  4      vResult tListOfResults ;
  5  begin
  6      select 'select ' || listagg (columnName, ' || '', '' || ') within group (order by columnName) || ' from someTable'
  7      into vSQL
  8      from tableOfColumns;
  9      --
 10      execute immediate vSQL bulk collect into vResult;
 11      if vResult.count() > 0 then
 12          for i in vResult.first .. vResult.last loop
 13              dbms_output.put_line(vResult(i));
 14          end loop;
 15      end if;
 16  end;
 17  /
1, 3
2, 6
3, 9

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: I am seeing syntax error in the above script. "Partially recognized rules(railroad diagrams):..

Comment: This error seems to have nothing to do with the Oracle code; how did you run it? Ad what is the complete error message?